# Jenkins and Maven, abort build on BUILD FAILURE during generate-test-resources

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, jenkins

This is a maven build, running on Jenkins. Version numbers listed at the end of this post. I'm trying to figure out how to abort my build when I get an error in the generate-test-resources phase.

**Requirement:** During maven's generate-test-resources phase, I have processes that run on a remote server (iSeries). From those calls, I retrieve a success flag (true or false). When I get false, I'd like to mark the ENTIRE build as BUILD FAILURE, and abort the build.

The code I run in generate-test-resources is in Java, but it submits jobs to the iSeries, and the real work is done in those submitted jobs.

**Rational:** My primary purpose of this build it to execute JUnit test cases. The generate-test-resources phase calls processes to initialize the test environment. If the generate-test-resources phase is not 100% successful, the tests will likely pass, but those results would be invalid.

Furthermore, when generate-test-resources has issues, but all the test cases pass, Jenkins reports BUILD SUCCESS. Very strange.

**Example:** Here is an example from my log. I know that my call to MY_BUILD_COMMAND calls back to the server correctly, and it is successful most days.  But when there is an error, I need to trap it.  Notice I have the status at "success? = false"

```
23:11:33.982 INFO  BuildTestEnvironment | -- Begin BuildTestEnvironment ---------------------
23:11:35.224 INFO  BuildTestEnvironment | Connected to VQ_INSCI10 as VQCINSCI10
23:11:35.292 INFO  qcmdExc | CALL QCMDEXC('MY_BUILD_COMMAND', 16)
23:11:35.621 FATAL qcmdExc | [CPF0006] Errors occurred in command.
java.sql.SQLException: [CPF0006] Errors occurred in command.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:646)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:617)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1401)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.execute(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1755)
    at main.java._tools.QcmdExc.run(QcmdExc.java:33)
    at main.java._tools.BuildTestEnvironment.main(BuildTestEnvironment.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
23:11:35.624 INFO  BuildTestEnvironment | success? = false
```

And then, at the end of the log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ VSP_UnitTest ---
[INFO] Installing /root/.jenkins/workspace/VSP_v10_Continuous/target/VSP_UnitTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/VSP_UnitTest/VSP_UnitTest/1.0-SNAPSHOT/VSP_UnitTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /root/.jenkins/workspace/VSP_v10_Continuous/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/VSP_UnitTest/VSP_UnitTest/1.0-SNAPSHOT/VSP_UnitTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:09:12.515s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 22 00:20:38 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/393M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/VSP_v10_Continuous/pom.xml to VSP_UnitTest/VSP_UnitTest/1.0-SNAPSHOT/VSP_UnitTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/VSP_v10_Continuous/target/VSP_UnitTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to VSP_UnitTest/VSP_UnitTest/1.0-SNAPSHOT/VSP_UnitTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: email@email.com
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

**Versions in use:**

- maven-complier-plugin = 2.3.2
- exec-maven-plugin = 1.3
- Jenkins ver. 1.539
- JUnit 4.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec-maven-plugin exec goal has a [successCodes](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#successCodes) element.  Typically on a Unix system, a command that runs successfully returns 0.  I'm wondering if the `false` returned by the test setup is being interpreted as 0 which would indicate Success as far as the plugin is concerned.  Try adding `<successCodes>1</successCodes>` to the plugin configuration and see if that causes the build to fail as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My java wasn't returning any code at all, so I would assume that is considered success=0. I added System.exit(i), and that tests out okay. Jenkins will attempt this tonight, and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok.  Turns out that if I return any exit code at all, Maven bails. So I set it to System.exit() when I actually have an error. Seems to be working okay.